# jQuery post/Ajax , one button locates different values of a table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i have created a code that displays some data from my database. And then the user can choose if he wants to open one of the `pdf files`.

Here's my problem:

> One Row

when the table has only one row , then the file opens **perfectly**.

> Two or more Rows

if my table has multiple  rows  then nothing happens.. **No errors** but also **no response**

*I have tried  to use the  `$(this).closest("tr")` but  is didn't work*

> My files
>
> displaySearchResults.php

```
<!--css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resultTable.css">
<!-- Display  Results -->
<div class="header">
<h1>Αποτελέσματα  Αναζήτησης <img src="" width></h1>
<hr> 
</div>

<div class="result_table">
<table>
<div>
<th>Όνομα Ιδιοκτήτη</th>
<th>Περιοχή</th>
<th>Οδός / Θέση</th>
<th>Οικοδομικό Τετράγωνο (Ο.Τ)</th>
<th>Έτος Ανασκαφής</th>
<th>Αριθμός Σχεδιαστικού  Αρχείου</th>
<th>Λέξεις Κλειδία</th>
<th>Αρχαιολόγος</th>
<th>Όνομα Αρχείου</th>
<th>Μέγεθος Αρχείου</th>
<th>Open file</th>
<th>Download file</th>
</div>
<div>
<?php

    while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['owner_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['area']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['street']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['building_block']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['key_words']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['archeologist']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?>
            <input type="hidden" id='filename' value='<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>'></td>
            <td><?php echo floor($row['size']/1000);
            echo "KB"; ?></td>
            <td><button class="button1" id="button1">OPEN</button></td>
            <td><button class="button2" id="button2">DOWNLOAD</button></td>

        </tr>
<?php
}


?>
</div>
</table>
</div>
<p  id="open"></p>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#button1").click(function(){
                //var extension = $(this).closest("tr").find(".Extension").text();
                var filename =  $("#filename").val();


                $.post("openFile.php", 
                {
                    filename: filename


                },function(data){
                    $("#open").html(data);

                });


           });
        });
</script>
```

> openFile.php

```
<?php 
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
echo "<iframe src=\"$filename\" width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\"></iframe>";
?>
```

Comment: You can not have multiple `id` in a single dom with the same value. This is most definitely giving you odd results than what you expect will happen. Switch to using `class` and define a button click on the class. In otherwords, never put an `id` in any sort of `while` `for` loop output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found my solution. Check if it's 100% correct.

> displaySearchResults

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resultTable.css">
<!-- Display  Results -->
<div class="header">
<h1>Αποτελέσματα  Αναζήτησης <img src="" width></h1>
<hr> 
</div>

<div class="result_table">
<table>
<div>
<th>Όνομα Ιδιοκτήτη</th>
<th>Περιοχή</th>
<th>Οδός / Θέση</th>
<th>Οικοδομικό Τετράγωνο (Ο.Τ)</th>
<th>Έτος Ανασκαφής</th>
<th>Αριθμός Σχεδιαστικού  Αρχείου</th>
<th>Λέξεις Κλειδία</th>
<th>Αρχαιολόγος</th>
<th>Όνομα Αρχείου</th>
<th>Μέγεθος Αρχείου</th>
<th>Open file</th>
<th>Download file</th>
</div>
<div>
<?php
    $x = 0 ;

    while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $x = $x + 1;

?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['owner_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['area']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['street']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['building_block']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['key_words']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['archeologist']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['filename']; ?>
            <input type="hidden" id='filename<?php echo $x?>' value='<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>'></td>
            <td><?php echo floor($row['size']/1000);
            echo "KB"; ?></td>
            <td><button id="button1<?php echo $x?>" class="button1">OPEN</button></td>
            <td><button id="button2<?php echo $x?>" class="button2">DOWNLOAD</button></td>

        </tr>

<?php
}


?>
<input type="hidden" id='buttonvalue' value='<?php echo $x; ?>'>


</div>
</table>
</div>
<p  id="open"></p>

<script>

function createCallback( i ){
  return function(){
    //alert('you clicked' + i);
    var filename =  $("#filename"+i).val();
                    $.post("openFile.php", 
                    {
                        filename: filename  
                    },function(data){
                        $("#open").html(data);

                    });


  }
  }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var x = $("#buttonvalue").val();
            for(var i = x; i > 0; i--) {

                $("#button1"+i).click(createCallback( i ));


           }

        });
</script>
```

> openFile.php

```
<?php 

$filename = $_POST['filename'];



echo "<iframe src=\"$filename\" width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\"></iframe>";

?>
```